# Java setReadTimeout() does not work

Tags: java, android, sockets

how and where would implement bellow a setReadTimeout or a setConnectTimeout?
My tests bellow always throw me error its undefined before compiling

When there is no connection it blocks at in.readLine() and the app waits forever

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://mydomain/myfile.php");

    //url.setReadTimeout(5000); does not work

    InputStreamReader testi= new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(testi);

        //in.setReadTimeout(5000); does not work

    stri = in.readLine();   
    Log.v ("GotThat: ",stri);
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

thanks for your help

chris

Comment: bufferedreader does not have a setReadTimeout method

Comment: ok.. thanks.
Any demo how to do the same as above example, but just with a timeout included?

Answer (score 1):

Use the URLConnection.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://mydomain/myfile.php");
 URLConnection connection = url.openConnection()
 int timeoutMs = 2000;
 connection.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs );

 InputStream urlInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlInputStream));

 String firstLine = in.readLine();   
 System.out.println("GotThat: " + firstLine);
 in.close();
```

This works for me.
Because of your comment christian Muller I tried it with several websites and adjusted the `timeoutMs` value. Set `timeoutMs` to 250 ms should cause a `SocketTimeoutException`. If you then increase it step by step you will see that finally you read a line.

For example if I try:

```
URL url = new URL("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
int timeoutMs = 250;
connection.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:695)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:640)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

If I try the same with 550 `timeoutMs` it works:

```
 GotThat: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Thanks.. but how would i come now to my

    stri = in.readLine();   
    Log.v ("GotThat: ",stri);
    in.close();
Anyhow i would need to read the textline thats in the file:
If u can lead me till that point, incl. the readtimeout is appreciated.. as      stri = in.readLine();   
after ur nice demo, just does not work